# How to create a funnel plot where the same color indicates effect sizes from the same studies

Tags: r, metafor

I am trying to create a `funnel plot` in `metafor` to test if there is a publication bias. In the funnel plot, I am trying to create the same color indicating effect sizes from the same studies. I recently came across a paper where they applied the same approach using the following code:

```
mod1 <- rma(yi, vi, data = dat3)
pdf(NULL)
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
par(mar=c(4,4,0.1,0) + 0.1)
funnel(mod1, col =inferno(25)[pos],
       ylim = c(0, 0.26), xlim = c(-0.6, 0.8),
       ylab = "Standard error (SE)", xlab = "Effect size (lnRR)")
```

I was just wondering what could  `inferno(25)[pos]` mean in the argument `col`. Does anyone know how to create such a funnel plot where the same color indicates effect sizes from the same studies?

Comment: Maybe look into [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/funnelR/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out how do it

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by pasting `data$esid` into `col` argument. Where `data` is your original data and `esid` is the unique id for each effect size

Comment: You can go ahead and accept your own answer.